# New Lead Assignment Email Notification sending email to user who triggered the Workflow

Tags: workflow, leads, email-alert

I have created a workflow rule to notify the lead owner when a new lead is assigned to the owner. However Lead owner is not getting any notifications.

Email Deliverability is set to 'All Email'
Rule is Active.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow seems to be correct just wanted to let you know that "id fields return 15 digit ids in workflow"  so if you are using 18 digit created by id, your workflow will not work